# ImportError: No module named random

Tags: python, import, window, anaconda, conda

I have installed Python in Windows 10 using Anaconda. However while it can `import sys` it can't `import random` or `import os`. Please suggest solutions.
http://pastebin.com/vu3U3pNt

```
C:\Users\mona>conda info
Current conda install:

               platform : win-64
          conda version : 4.2.9
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.2.9
    conda-build version : 2.0.2
         python version : 3.5.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.11.1
       root environment : C:\Program Files\Anaconda3  (read only)
    default environment : C:\Program Files\Anaconda3
       envs directories : C:\Users\mona\.conda\envs
                          C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs
          package cache : C:\Users\mona\.conda\envs\.pkgs
                          C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch/
            config file : None
           offline mode : False
```

So in renderdoc it can't import os however in cmd when I use Python interactive shell it can:
[image]
This is the output of sys.version in RenderDoc Python Interactive shell `2.7.4 (IronPython 2.7.4 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (64-bit))`

```
C:\Users\mona>python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import random
```

I wonder if someone knows why is that and how to solve it?
Here's what I see in the interactive shell of RenderDoc Python:

```
RenderDoc Python console, powered by IronPython 2.7.4.1000
The 'renderdoc' object is the Core class instance.
```

Also notice that:

```
config = {}
config['py_lib_dir']  = 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\'      # where we find the Python libraries
config['save_dir']    = 'D:/gta5_extracted/' # where we store extraction results
# creates a prefixes for files and directories from logfilename
config['dir_prefix']  = lambda logFilename : ''       
config['file_prefix'] = lambda logFilename : basename(logFilename)[:-4] + '_'
import sys
print(sys.version)
sys.path.append(config['py_lib_dir'])
from os import mkdir
```

Gives the error:

```
2.7.4 (IronPython 2.7.4 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (64-bit))
Extracting from frame 0
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\os.py", line 407
                    yield from walk(entry.path, topdown, onerror, followlinks)

                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected token 'from'
```

Comment: Why not installing Python with the regular way using its [binaries](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) ? I never tried Anaconda.

Comment: Make sure that python installed properly. Or re install it. There is no reason to look like that.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam did you see the pastebin? it seems it is installed correctly

Comment: It seems you installed Anaconda for linux-64-bit.

Comment: As far as I remember I followed the instruction for Win10 x64!

Comment: It is strange that for most packages there is only "linux-64" or "linux-32" in the "Platforms" column on the pastebin. Though I don't know the details of installation Anaconda, maybe that's ok.

Comment: @Wolfram please see the updates in the question.

Comment: Anaconda3 is for Python 3, but the python running in your renderdoc is 2.7. "yield from" is incorrect syntax in Python 2, thus the error. Check interpreter settings for renderdoc and set Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it fixed by replacing these lines (had both versions installed):

```
#config['py_lib_dir']  = 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\'      # where we find the Python libraries
config['py_lib_dir']  = 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda2\\Lib\\'
```

Comment: If your answer fixed the problem, you can check it as verified to help the others :)

Comment: it requires two days in order to let me accept my answer but sure :)